# Using WindowBuilder in Eclipse to add SWT TableView window to existing program

Tags: swt, jface, windowbuilder

I've installed WindowBuilder in Eclipse Juno and am able to create Details Page. The generated source code:

```
    /**
 * Initialize the details page.
 * @param form
 */
public void initialize(IManagedForm form) {
    managedForm = form;
}

/**
 * Create contents of the details page.
 * @param parent
 */
public void createContents(Composite parent) {
    FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
    parent.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    //
```

requires a ManagedForm to be initialised. A a very Java newbie I've been completely stuck as to where to get this object. I've probably missed the obvious but help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `ManagedForm` class. Create a new class that inherits from ManagedForm and you got yourself an `IManagedForm` implementation:

```
public class MyManagedForm extends ManagedForm {
    public MyManagedForm(Composite parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
}
```

I'd recommend using an Editor like Eclipse and getting the source code into it so that you can easily browse the documentation and the API's classes in general. [Lars Vogel's introduction to Eclipse APIs](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseForms/article.html) is a good read, too.